# Xamarin Forms - Could not load file or assembly SkiaSharp.Views.Forms

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, xunit

I am trying to unit-test a viewmodel but when I try to do that it gives me the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'SkiaSharp.Views.Forms

I included the nuget package in the test project via the nuget package manager, but it still complains about not being able to find the file/assembly. Why is that?

Comment: Did you get any solution?